# Typo in Atkinson?

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods

This is problem 6.14 from Atkinson's Intro to Numerical Analysis.

> How can the two step method $y_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(y_n+y_{n+1})+\frac{h}{4}(4y_{n+1}'-y_n'+3y_{n-1}')$ be second-order?

It doesn't even seem to be first-order to me. Is there a typo?

Comment: It should read: $y_{n+2}=...$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a typo . . . but it appears to be your typo.  You transcribed the problem incorrectly.  I checked problem 6.14 in a scanned pdf version of the second edition of the text on-line (page 452) and it reads

$y_{n + 1}  = \frac{1}{2}\left( {y_n  + y_{n - 1} } \right) + \frac{h}{4}\left( {4y'_{n + 1}  - y'_n  + 3y'_{n - 1} } \right)$

I also have the first edition of the text, and it also has the equation properly rendered as I've given it (problem 6.10 in the first edition).

It is now easy to show that this, correctly written two-step method, is a second-order method.  You can, for example, use the results in Atkinson’s section on multi-step methods or follow Atkinson’s discussion of the method of undetermined coefficients.  I did just that, and confirmed that the method that I expressed above is in fact second-order (i.e., there is no typo for this problem in the Atkinson text itself).